# Remote mysql server constantly stopping and rebooting

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have made a django chatting application that allows users to talk to one anoter. I am using websockets for chatting and a MySQL server as my database.
Since a few days, the MySQL database (or the server itself) has been rebooting non stop. This is happening so frequently that I am getting an error in my django application
that while a message that was sent was being sent by a user was being saved in the database, the connection was lost. I am also unable to load messages in chats, meaning
the previous messages being sent by the user are not visible either. The other functionalities of the database seem to be working fine for some reason such as the
profile being updated, your account info being stored accurately. The site temporarily works fine if I restart the server with the "sudo shutdown -r now" command but I get the same problem not too long after that.
If you want, you can check out the functionality of the site over at https://aniconnect.org

Here is the output when I do the journalctl command:

```
gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo journalctl -u mysql
Sep 20 13:18:17 animechatapp systemd[1]: Starting mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
Sep 20 13:18:18 animechatapp systemd[1]: Started mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Oct 13 08:28:45 animechatapp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 13 08:28:45 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopped mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Oct 13 08:28:45 animechatapp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 1h 32min 45.508s CPU time.
Oct 13 08:28:45 animechatapp systemd[1]: Starting mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
Oct 13 08:28:46 animechatapp systemd[1]: Started mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Oct 13 08:47:00 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopping mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
Oct 13 08:47:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 13 08:47:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopped mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Oct 13 08:47:02 animechatapp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 4.195s CPU time.
-- Boot 4b053cef278948d2b1c15ebc9add886d --
Oct 13 08:48:23 animechatapp systemd[1]: Starting mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
Oct 13 08:48:27 animechatapp systemd[1]: Started mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Oct 17 06:50:09 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopping mysql.service - MySQL Community Server...
Oct 17 06:50:11 animechatapp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Deactivated successfully.
Oct 17 06:50:11 animechatapp systemd[1]: Stopped mysql.service - MySQL Community Server.
Oct 17 06:50:11 animechatapp systemd[1]: mysql.service: Consumed 17min 43.573s CPU time.
-- Boot 663ec237c1424bd295c0df89dcc4f29b --
```

The following is the output of the daphne status command:

```
gamedeveloper@animechatapp:~$ sudo systemctl status daphne.service
● daphne.service - Daphne ASGI Server for Your Django Project
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/daphne.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-10-31 08:46:08 UTC; 1 day 21h ago
   Main PID: 520 (daphne)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 994)
     Memory: 37.8M
        CPU: 33.250s
     CGroup: /system.slice/daphne.service
             └─520 /home/gamedeveloper/venv/bin/python /home/gamedeveloper/venv/bin/daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8001 anime_chat_app.asgi:application

Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:     return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 179, in execute
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:     res = self._query(mogrified_query)
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 330, in _query
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:     db.query(q)
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:   File "/home/gamedeveloper/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 255, in query
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]:     _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
Nov 02 06:13:06 animechatapp daphne[520]: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')
```

My database config in settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default':{
                'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'NAME':'anime_chat_app',
                'USER':'myuser',
                'PASSWORD':'my_password',
                'HOST':'the_host',
                'PORT':'3306',
                }
}
```

My JS code in chatroom.html:

```
<script>

    document.querySelector('#submit').onclick = function (e) {
        const messageInputDOM = document.querySelector('#input');
        const message = messageInputDOM.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message,
            'username': userUsername,
            'user_pfp':userPfp,
            'room_name':roomName
        }));
        messageInputDOM.value = '';
    };

    const chatMessagesDOM = document.querySelector('#chat-messages');
    const userUsername = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('user_username').textContent);
    const pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    const roomName = pathArray[pathArray.length - 2];
   const chatSocket = new WebSocket(
    (window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss://' : 'ws://') +
    'aniconnect.org'+
    '/ws/chat/' +
    roomName +
    '/'
);

chatSocket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection closed. Code:', event.code, 'Reason:', event.reason);
};
    chatSocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('WebSocket connection opened.');
};


chatSocket.onerror = function (error) {
    console.log('WebSocket error:', error);
};
    chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
    const data = JSON.parse(e.data);

    const messageContainer = document.createElement('div');
    messageContainer.classList.add('chat-message');

    let profilePicture = document.createElement('img');
    profilePicture.src = data.user_pfp;
    profilePicture.classList.add('profile-picture');
    messageContainer.appendChild(profilePicture);

    const messageContent = document.createElement('span');

    const usernameSpan = document.createElement('span');
    usernameSpan.textContent = data.username + ': ';
    messageContent.appendChild(usernameSpan);

    const messageSpan = document.createElement('span');
    messageSpan.textContent = data.message;
    messageContent.appendChild(messageSpan);

    messageContainer.appendChild(messageContent);

    chatMessagesDOM.appendChild(messageContainer);
};
</script>
```

Since this is might be an error exclusive to websockets, here is my consumers.py file:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async
from .models import ChatRoom, Message, Profile
from asyncer import asyncify

@sync_to_async
def save_message_to_database(chatroom_name, username, message):
    try:
        chatroom = ChatRoom.objects.get(name=chatroom_name)
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        new_message = Message.objects.create(chat_room=chatroom, sender=user_profile, content=message)
        print("Message saved to DB:", new_message)

    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"Chatroom with name '{chatroom_name}' does not exist.")

    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        print(f"User profile with username '{username}' does not exist.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred while saving the message: {e}")



@sync_to_async
def get_chatroom_by_name(name):
    try:
        return ChatRoom.objects.get(name=name)
    except ChatRoom.DoesNotExist:
        return None
@sync_to_async
def get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom):
    return list(Message.objects.filter(chat_room=chatroom).order_by('timestamp'))

class ChatRoomConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
        print("Before getting chatroom")
        chatroom = await get_chatroom_by_name(self.room_name)

        print("chatroom:",chatroom)

        print("Chatroom:",chatroom)
        messages = await get_messages_for_chatroom(chatroom.id)
        for message in messages:
            print("SENDING MESSAGE TO FUNCTION")
            await self.send_message_to_client(message)



    async def send_message_to_client(self, message):
        user_id = await sync_to_async(lambda: message.sender.user_id)()
        user = await sync_to_async(lambda: User.objects.get(id=user_id))()
        print("SENDING MESSAGES TO THE FRONTEND")
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message.content,
            'username': user.username,
            'user_pfp': message.sender.profile_picture.url,
            'room_name': self.room_name,
        }))

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        username = text_data_json['username']
        user_pfp = text_data_json['user_pfp']
        room_name = text_data_json['room_name']

        await save_message_to_database(chatroom_name=room_name, username=username, message=message)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chatroom_message',
                'message': message,
                'username': username,
                'user_pfp': user_pfp,
                'tester_message': 'tester message in receive function'
            }
        )
    async def chatroom_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']
        user_pfp = event['user_pfp']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
            'user_pfp': user_pfp,
            'tester_message': 'tester message in chatroom message'
        }))
```

Please help me out!

Comment: If your mysql server constantly restarts, then you need to find out what causes it. The logs you show contain no clues. Perhaps mysql's error log tells you what's going on. Most likely it is not a programming issue.

Comment: @Shadow there are no errors in the error log file. It's empty

Comment: In the absence of errors, it is impossible to tell what has gone wrong. You may have to design some experiments to narrow down the root cause. For example, do not use your app for a longer period of time. If mysql does not restart in that timeframe, then most likely it is your app that causes the issue. You will probably need to run multiple such experiments.

Comment: What makes you think _"MySQL database (or the server itself) has been rebooting non stop"_? The error message is _probably_ caused by the db connection timing out.

Comment: @user1191247 check out the first log the OP provided in the question...

Comment: @Shadow Thanks, I did read it all. There is nothing in the mysql journal output that correlates with the lost connection at `Nov 02 06:13:06`. It seems _likely_ that the lost connections are due to them being long running connections that are being closed by the MySQL instance. There is nothing to indicate _"rebooting non stop"_. Three MySQL service shutdowns since Sep 20 (two of which were _probably_ user commanded server reboots).

Comment: Additional DB information request from the 'remote mysqlserver constantly restarting, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME - if possible.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @Shadow I did some debugging and found out the issue is most likely with my websockets code because I am able to login, register and do other things that require my database to function properly. It's only the chatting functionality that isn't working fine, the rest of the database is fine.

Comment: @WilsonHauck my apologies for the late reply, I did some debugging and found out the issue is most likely with my chatting functionality itself as the rest of the things like logging in and registering is working just fine. Meaning the database isn't actually rebooting but it just SEEMS to shut down all the processes related to the chatting itself. I have provided the logic used in the backend (consumers.py) and the front end JS code so please help me out.

Comment: @user1191247 apologies for the late reply, I did some debugging and found out the issue is most likely with my chatting functionality itself as the rest of the things like logging in and registering is working just fine. Meaning the database isn't actually rebooting but it just SEEMS to shut down all the processes related to the chatting itself. I have provided the logic used in the backend (consumers.py) and the front end JS code so please help me out.

Comment: I am not a python dev, so cannot be of much help. The only thing that jumped out at me when reading [Channels->Database Access](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html) is the suggestion to use [`channels.db.database_sync_to_async`](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html#database-sync-to-async) instead of `asgiref.sync.sync_to_async` for ORM calls. This _"cleans up database connections on exit"_, meaning there won't be timed out db connections hanging around.

Comment: @FuzzAshes  Please let me know when you have posted A) Additional DB information requested 2023-11-03 23:39 and B) TEXT information requested 2023-11-03 23:39.  I may be able to assist you once that information is posted and you share the links.